# Is it possible for a root element not be of complex type and have two global tags?

Tags: oracle11g, xsd, root

I am asking this question becaules oracle 11g doesnt allow a child element to complex type to be deleted. I want to add a new global element and delete the same. All examples I have seen so far has the root element as complex type.

Answer (score 0):

It is usual for the root element of a document to have a complex type, because when it has a simple type the document is required to be either very very simple or invalid.  However, there is no requirement in XSD that the root element have a complex type; XSD does not identify the root element as such, so it cannot in fact impose any special constraints on it at all.

If by "and have two global tags" you mean "is it possible for an XSD schema to define two top-level elements?" the answer is yes.